# How to get data from coinapi when only press a button flutter

Tags: api, flutter, http

I'm using this link from the coinapi web but it gives real time data I want a data when I press a button need solution or coinapi link I've read the coinapi complete documentation but I cant find any solution over there need a link or solution that gives me data when I clicked a button or when I require some data from coinapi.

code here:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
      double dollars;
      String selectedValue = "USD";
      List<DropdownMenuItem> getDropDown() {
        List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [];
        for (String items in list) {
          var item = DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(items),
            value: items,
          );
          menuItems.add(item);
        }
        return menuItems;
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        getNetData();
      }
    
      void getNetData() async {
        HTTP.Response response = await HTTP.get(
            'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/BTC/USD?apikey=myKey';
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          setState(() {
            dollars = jsonDecode(response.body)['rate'];
          });
        } else
          print('Error');
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        getNetData();
        getDropDown();
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Card(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            '1 BTC = $dollars USD DOLLAR',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        value: selectedValue,
                        items: getDropDown(),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedValue = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code in `build` and `initState` methods you retrieving the data from WEB but is not correct. If you need get the data each time when screen opening, you can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget (with it you can add a loader to providing information about current data retrieving state) and not call `getNetData` from `initState`. For update the data from a button (if you are choose `FutureBuilder`), just call `setState` (which calls `build` method again and reload value).

Something like this:

```dart
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  String selectedValue = "USD";

  Future<String> getRate() async {
    HTTP.Response response = await HTTP.get('https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/BTC/$selectedValue?apikey=myKey');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body)['rate'];
    } else {
      // TODO: handle error code correctly
      return '';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: getRate(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          // The data is loading, show progress
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        final rate = snapshot.data;
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Card(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            '1 BTC = $rate USD DOLLAR',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        value: selectedValue,
                        items: getDropDown(),
                        onChanged: (value) => setState(() {}),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem> getDropDown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [];
    for (String items in list) {
      var item = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(items),
        value: items,
      );
      menuItems.add(item);
    }
    return menuItems;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I've added my API key but from this real time data is receiving I want to receive data once when I press a button.